# How to access the values of this API return

Tags: php, arrays, object

Could you please help me? I need to know how to access the values of this response from an API call using PHP.

Array ( [queryIds] => Array ( [0] => lHLLapn7EH ) [timedOutRealtimeData] => [realtimeDataMissing] => [cacheFreshness] => FRESH [prunedResult] => [novaCost] => 0 [novaRequestDuration] => 19 [wasCached] => 1 [minSampleRate] => 1 [timeComputed] => 1558794556710 [novaRuntime] => 199 [hitChunkGroupByLimit] => [throttleTime] => 0 [data] => Array ( [series] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [setId] => [value] => 843 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [setId] => [value] => 22 ) ) ) [seriesLabels] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => C5241; GB ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => C9999; GB ) ) [seriesMeta] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [eventGroupBys] => Array ( [0] => C5241 [1] => GB ) [segmentIndex] => 0 [eventIndex] => 0 [eventGroupBy] => C5241; GB ) [1] => Array ( [eventGroupBys] => Array ( [0] => C9999 [1] => GB ) [segmentIndex] => 0 [eventIndex] => 0 [eventGroupBy] => C9999; GB ) ) [seriesCollapsed] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [setId] => [value] => 843 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [setId] => [value] => 22 ) ) ) [xValues] => Array ( [0] => 2019-05-25 ) ) [partialMergedAndNewUserInformation] => [transformationIds] => Array ( [0] => 2696 ) [backend] => novaV2 )

Comment: Which index value you need ?

Comment: Without seeing the more complicated version of the data no-one can really give an answer that is guaranteed to work when you do have that data. Also there are two `Array ( [0] => C9999 [1] => GB )` in your data so it's unclear which one you want.

Comment: I need this one Array ( [0] => C9999 [1] => GB ) ,  [xValues] => Array ( [0] => 2019-05-25and I need Array ( [setId] => [value] => 20, the problem is that this is simple at some point I'll have like many of them and I need to know the way how to access them to send them to a database, I need a loop where I can get the code C#### conforming the array will grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them using

```
 Array ( [0] => C9999 [1] => GB )  -> $arr['data']['seriesMeta'][0]['eventGroupBys']

Array ( [setId] => [value] => 20) -> $arr['data']['seriesMeta'][0][0]
```

Comment: But is there a way in PHP to access those values if they change like in a loop? I just added another code to the API response.